# Magento recurring profile status

Tags: magento-1.9, recurring

When and how recurring profile status changes into "EXPIRED" while reaching maximum billing cycles. Can any one explain it briefly.

Answer (score 0):

Generally expired status is when a profile subscription period is completed.

You can find more info in [Documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables/)